# sql subquery group by

Tags: sql, t-sql

i need some assistance with a SQL query:
the data looks like this:

```
ID (int, PK)
REF (int, FK)
UserName (varchar)
TransDate (DateTime)
Status (int)

1, 1001, joebloggs, 2011-12-15 13:50:01, 1
2, 1001, johnsmith, 2011-12-15 14:35:01, 1
```

so i need to return the REF and Username for the following; MIN(TransDate) and where status = 1.

so i do the following:

```
    SELECT  REF, UserName, MIN(TransDate )
    FROM          dbo.MyTable
    WHERE      (Status = 1)
    and REF = 1001
    GROUP BY REF, UserName
```

obviously this is wrong because it returns me:

```
1001, joebloggs, 2011-12-15 13:50:01
1001, johnsmith, 2011-12-15 14:35:01
```

however, i just need to return the username of the min transDate. so:

```
1001, joebloggs, 2011-12-15 13:50:01
```

can anyone help me please..its driving me insane.

thanks (from my sanity)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT REF, UserName, TransDate
FROM dbo.MyTable    
WHERE ID = (
    SELECT TOP 1 ID
    FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE Status = 1 AND REF = 1001
    ORDER BY TransDate ASC
)
```

EDIT:

Or, if you need the results for each REF, instead of a specific REF, you can try this:

```
SELECT mt.REF, mt.UserName, mt.TransDate
FROM 
    dbo.MyTable mt JOIN (
        SELECT
            REF,
            MIN(TransDate) AS MinTransDate
        FROM dbo.MyTable
        WHERE Status = 1
        GROUP BY REF
    ) MinResult mr ON mr.REF = mt.REF AND mr.MinTransDate = mt.TransDate
```

Comment: is it possible to do the second statement wihtout a CTE? thanks btw

Answer (score 2):

How about doing it this way?

```
SELECT TOP(1) REF, UserName, TransDate
FROM dbo.MyTable
WHERE (Status = 1)
and REF = 1001
ORDER BY TransDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT  REF, UserName, MIN(TransDate )
FROM          dbo.MyTable
WHERE      (Status = 1)
and REF = 1001
and transdate=(select min(transdate) from dbo.MyTable)
GROUP BY REF, UserName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost there.  Use a subquery to locate the min_date, then join back to the original table for the rest of the data.

```
select * from dbo.mytable
inner join (select min(transdate)
FROM          dbo.MyTable
WHERE      (Status = 1)
and REF = 1001) a
on mytable.transdate = a.transdate
```

This solution will return multiple rows if you have multiple records with the same trans_date

Answer (score -1):

Add an `order by` and a `Limit 1`:

Comment: This is SQL Server, not MySQL.